# Reducing Iterations During Math Factoring

Tags: java, math

I need assistance with refactoring the inner loop. I would like a more efficient way including less iterations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");


        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            if ((i % j) == 0)
                System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Here is what I have attempted thus far:

```
 int j = 2;
        do{
        if ((i % j) == 0) System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
        j++;
    } while (j < 2);
```

This only prints out the first factor and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to through the whole list. I know I am missing something semantically but it is making me pull my hair out.

Comment: `do` ... `while (j < 2)` will repeat the loop only while `j` is less than 2.  And it never is.  So the loop repeats only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate up to `i`.  Just `sqrt(i)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i= 2 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
        int limit= (int)Math.sqrt(i) ;
        for(int j= 2 ; j <= limit ; j++ )
            if( i % j == 0 ) {
                System.out.print( j + " " );
                System.out.print( (i/j) + " " );
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

BTW, do you need all divisors?  Decomposition in prime factors is much faster.  The result is also much more concise and easy to understand and use.

Comment: if `i` is 40 this will not print out 20 as one of the factors.  Also, `j <= Math.sqrt(i)` will recompute the square root of `i` in every iteration, which is relatively time-consuming--why not `j * j <= i` ?

Comment: But doesn't this just produce the same number of iterations?
    for (int j = 2; j*j<=i; j++)

Comment: @ajb  Your comment about ` sqrt` is completely true.  But in most circumstances, program clarity is much more important than program performance.

Comment: @6paq  Of course not!  When i= 100, `j <= i` stops when j=100.  `j*j <= i` stops when j=10.

Comment: @6paq  I modified the code so it's more apparent.  I insist on using `Math.sqrt` for clarity even if up to 10 calculations of `j*j` could be faster.

Comment: If `i` is a perfect square, this will print the square root twice.  You may have to modify `limit` in that case.

Comment: @Teepeemm  That's absolutely right.  Thanks a lot for pointing it out.  Let's leave modification of the code to the OP?

Answer (score 3):

You only need to run your `j` for loop from `2` through `Math.sqrt(i)`, because if you have found a factor `j` of `i` that is less than or equal to `Math.sqrt(i)`, then you have also found the corresponding factor `i/j` that is greater than or equal to `Math.sqrt(i)` and you can print that factor also (unless `j == i/j`, then don't print the same factor twice).

Comment: So sorry if I'm sounding thick headed here but I am not understanding where the i/j method comes into play: 

    for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i) | j==i/j; j++)

This still has the missing factors in the 40's etc that has been mentioned before.

Comment: Use `for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++)` to start your loop.  In the loop body, if you found that `j` is a factor, print it as you've done already.  Then, if `j != `i/j`, then you've found another factor and can print it too.  That should find your `20` if `i` is `40`, because `j` is 2 and `i/j` is 20.

Comment: @MarioRossi Ah, forgive me - you are correct.  Though I feel that this answer explains why it works a little better, even if it doesn't have it in code. (I will remove my previous comment as it is misleading.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many optimizations possible. Here are just a few:

- you can stop trial division at the square root, since if `j` is a factor, so is `i/j`
- you can determine prime factors and combine them to factors of the number
- for finding prime factors it is enough to do trial division by primes
- if the number is large, there exist other factorization methods faster than trial division